# Php MySQL параметр по умолчанию

Tags: mysqli, php, mysql

Здравствуйте! Я новичок  PHP и MySQL. У меня есть таблица, где по умолчанию стоит строка со значением author varchar(11) и значение по умолчанию 'Nancy'.
Пытаюсь его вставить в php:

```
$sel = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO entry(author, date, header, content) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?) ");
    $time = time();
    $NAME = $mysqli->query("SELECT `author` FROM `entry WHERE `id` = 1");
    $NAME['author'] = htmlspecialchars($NAME['author']);
    $sel->bind_param('siss', $NAME['author'], $time, $_POST['header'], $_POST['content']);
    if ($sel->execute()) {
        header('Location: .');
    } else {
        die(mysql_error());
    }
```

Вставляется все кроме автора. Я глубокий новичок, поэтому могут быть глупые и банальный на взгляд профессионалов ошибки. Будьте благосклонны)) Спасибо!

**Обновление**

```
$sel = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO entry(date, header, content) VALUES(?, ?, ?) ");
        $time = time();
        $NAME = $mysqli->query("SELECT `author` FROM `entry WHERE `id` = 1");
        $NAME['author'] = htmlspecialchars($NAME['author']);
        $sel->bind_param('iss', $NAME['author'], $time, $_POST['header'], $_POST['content']);
```

> "Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param():
> Number of elements in type definition
> string doesn't match number of bind
> variables " $NAME['author']

вообще убрать? как тогда быть?

Comment: > mysql_error()

из другого модуля, не покажет оно ошибку для mysqli

Comment: Все равно, проблему это не решает увы...

Comment: @AKhorevich, значение по умолчанию - это то значение, которое проставится, если при INSERT не придет никаких данных об этом поле. Пустая строка считается за вполне годные данные. Конкретно в запрос в `author` вообще идет `'siss'`.

Answer (score 1):

у entry только один обратный апостроф:

```
"SELECT `author` FROM `entry WHERE `id` = 1"
```

Comment: исправила, но все равно не получется